# SQL error on changing the page number to large number

Tags: magento2.3

I have a strange problem. Whenever I change the page number to some none existing page number then the system throws `sql` error.

For example `http://domain.com/category.html?p=1` works as expected but when I change it to `http://domain.com/category.html?p=100` then it throws below error. In that category only `1-5` pages available.

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') ASC' at line
>   4, query was: SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`,
>   `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`,
>   IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price,
>   price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`,
>   `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`,
>   `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS
>   `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS
>   `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable`
>   FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
>   price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
>   AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id =
>   review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND
>   review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM
>   `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))  INNER JOIN
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id
>   = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE ((stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (e.entity_id IN (NULL)))
>   AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) ORDER BY
>   FIELD(e.entity_id,) ASC

As you can see some `SQL` is missing after `FIELD(e.entity_id,`. This is how it should be:

> SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`,
>   `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL,
>   LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price),
>   price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`,
>   `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`,
>   IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`,
>   IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`,
>   `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM
>   `catalog_product_entity` AS `e`  INNER JOIN
>   `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON
>   price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.website_id = '1'
>   AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0  LEFT JOIN
>   `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id =
>   review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND
>   review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM
>   `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product'))  INNER JOIN
>   `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id
>   = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE ((stock_status_index.stock_status = 1) AND (e.entity_id IN (NULL)))
>   AND (e.created_in <= 1) AND (e.updated_in > 1) ORDER BY
>   FIELD(e.entity_id,NULL) ASC

It looks `NULL` is missing.

Diff image: [image]

Magento 2.3.3 with elasticsearch 6+

**Any idea why this happening? Which section should I be checking to fix this?**

Comment: please share your code for more information

Comment: It's a Magento core code. I haven't made any changes. And I confirm it is doing this only when using `elasticsearch`. With mysql search, it's working fine.

Comment: So please check which value comes Null in your core code.

Answer (score 0):

try this way to  get collection

```
$page = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('p')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('p') : 1; \\ default value 

$pageSize = ($this->getRequest()->getParam('limit')) ? $this->getRequest()->getParam('limit') : 5; \\ default value 

$collection = .................................. \\ get your collection here 
$collection->setPageSize($pageSize);
$collection->setCurPage($page);
return $collection;
```

> And if you filter dynamic value must check value not **NULL**